# Terra Character Files: Missing Daisy Duck and Enchanted Brooms

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep, kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

I have completed every report with Terra on the Journal, but I am missing 2 entries in the character files: Daisy Duck and Enchanted Brooms. I read that you have to complete the game with every player and then finish the Dream Festival in Disney Town to get them. Is there anything I can do to get 100% for Terra's journal, without needing to do everything again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I had completely forgot to beat **No Heart** in the Mirage Arena (probably beacause it is not needed for completing the Arena missions). For everyone that has the same problem in the future, Daisy Duck and Enchanted Brooms are not needed to complete the character files.